# Max no.of records can we test in selenium by using data driven framework

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have one scenario say example In shoppong cart web application , in the ceckout page while selecting the address,I have two drop downs
which are states and city. we needd to select the state and city and need to validate delivery charge based on the state and city

Here my question is, I am taking the all states with city names together as a pair in a CSV file and I am executing the above said scenario for each pair of state and city.So my doubt is how many max number of records is it capable to do.

Note: In my current execution it was executing up to max 136 records after that it was terminating the execution and also I am logging the success condition  to console and failure condition to text file.
My Enviroment : Selenium webdriver with javascript(node.js) + mocha framework +windows+excel sheet(800)

Comment: What terminated the execution? The test runner? The Selenium session? something else?

Comment: No, its just terminates with the error. the error was not able to find the dropdown. I debugged with that particular record then its executing fine. Don't know .how we can find the "Selenium session time out" and "test runner"?

Comment: If the error was that Selenium was not able to find the dropdown value, then probably Selenium and the test runner are not timing out. Are you certain that the desired dropdown value was present? Might the app be slowing down in some way, so that the value is not yet loaded at the moment when Selenium tries to find it? (Asynchrony can be a big nuisance.)

Comment: Yes may be slowing down the application is the reason bcoz of async behave . Is there any way to test this senario ?

Comment: I usually try to record a video, and see if that gives me any information. Another thing to do: Poll for the element. That is: Try to find the element. If Selenium throws an error, catch it. Then pause for (say) 1 second and try again. And again. And again. My clients use polling loops like this all the time, retrying once per second for as long as 90 seconds.

Comment: Thank you @Dale Emery. Can  you provide me the sample snippet for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a set limit does not exist and tests should run until you stop them. I do wonder if you really need to check all pairs and if isn't that easier checked in a unit-test. It should also be possible to write unit-tests for JavaScript actions that populate drop-downs. Check only a couple of pairs in the actual GUI, because testing all pairs with Selenium feels like a waste of time.

Maybe you are running into a Browser issue (maybe memory issues in the client side code after repeating the same over and over again).

If you cannot find the cause to the halt (because its to time consuming to debug) try to split up the tests in a couple of smaller ones that each try a 100 combinations instead.